# Append CSV Data to Apache Superset Dataset

Tags: apache-superset

Using CSV upload in Apache Superset works as expected. I can use it to add data from CSV to a databse, e.g. Postgres. Now I want to apped data from a different CSV to this table/dataset. But how?

The CSVs all have the same format. But there is a new one for every day. In the end I want to have a dashboard which updates every day, taking the new data into account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, I agree with Ana that if you want to repeatedly upload new CSV data then you're better off operationalizing this into some type of process, pipeline, etc that runs on a schedule.

But if you need to stick with the uploading CSV route through the Superset UI, then you can set the **Table Exists** field to **Append** instead of **Replace**.

You can find a helpful GIF in the Preset docs: https://docs.preset.io/docs/tips-tricks#append-csv-to-a-database

Comment: I accepted your answer since it does what I asked for. But after further research I will probably go the path Ana suggested. At least for the daily CSVs. For Data with a new CSV each Month or so, your solution should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you'll be better served by creating a simple process to load the CSV to a table in the database and then querying that table in Superset.
Superset is a tool to visualize data, it allows uploading CSV for quick and dirty "only once" kind of charts, but if this is going to be a recurrent and structured periodical load of data, it's better to use whatever integrating tool you want to load the data, there are zillions of ETL (Extract-Transform-Load) tools out there (or scripting programs to do it), ask if your company is already using one, or choose the one that is simpler for you.